# Switching to a nested route is automatically running the last commit event from parent's store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, vuex-modules

**Reproduction link**
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-c2gtb

**Steps to reproduce**

```
Open https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-c2gtb
Click on 'Go to Page with nested router' link
Click on 'commit event', it will show an alert box
Now change the nested route by clicking 'change nested route to reporting'
```

**What is expected?**
Route changed to reporting without showing the 'hello' alert box.

**What is actually happening?**
Its showing the 'hello' alert box again.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your watcher to ignore cases when old value is the same as new value:

```
    watch: {
        event: {
            handler(newVal,oldVal) {
                if(oldVal === newVal) return; // <--- the important part
                switch (this.event.id) {
                    case 'new_requirement': {
                        alert('hello');
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                }
            },
        },
    },
```

Comment: so I need to add this comparison to all of my watchers :S

Comment: Apparently - if you want to avoid such "fake" fires :)